# How to calculate probability of taking 4 cards of the same rank successively?

Tags: probability

I'm trying figure out what is probability of picking 4 cards of the same rank successively from 52 card set (no jokers). Almost duplicate with [Probability of having two cards of the same rank amongst n cards](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1716058/probability-of-having-two-cards-of-the-same-rank-amongst-n-cards), but I'm interested on having exactly 4 cards, not two (so there is easily can be mistake if I apply the gained knowledge in this case :)).

So as I assume that the probability should be equal to: $\frac{52}{52}*\frac{3}{51}*\frac{2}{50}*\frac{1}{49}$. Hence, 1st turn is 1 (no matter what the card I take), then 3/51 (3 because there is remained only 3 cards of the same rank and 51, because 1 card we've already taken from prev.turn), the 3rd turn is 2/50 (the same way as previous reasoning) and at 4th is 1/49. Do I think right?

Comment: Yes, you think right.

Comment: ...or, if you want, $\frac{4}{52} \frac{3}{51} \frac{2}{50} \frac{1}{49} \times 13$

Comment: @Alex that's interesting, could you post the explained version of this and I accept it!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You solved the problem by not specifying the first card picked (which is correct). If you wish, you can specify this, and you have 13 options (Ace, King, etc) for the first card to be picked. Hence it is 
$$
13 \times \frac{4}{52} \frac{3}{51} \frac{2}{50} \frac{1}{49}
$$